# Maintain SUM but limit select

Tags: mysql, sql

I already have the following query:

```
SELECT `c`.`id`, `cake`, `description`, `image`, SUM(`i`.`calories`) AS `calories`,  SUM(`i`.`sell_price`) AS `sell_price`, SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(`i`.`time`))) as `time`, MIN(`i`.`stock`) AS `stock`
FROM `cakes` `c`
LEFT JOIN `recipes` `r`
    ON `c`.`id` = `r`.`cakes_id`
LEFT JOIN `ingredients` `i`
    ON `r`.`ingredients_id` = `i`.`id`
WHERE `r`.`ingredients_id` = ?
GROUP BY `c`.`id`
```

The tables:
Cake:

```
| id | cake      | description |
|  1 | chocolate |             |
|  2 | Example   |             |
```

Recipe:

```
| id | cake_id | ingredient_id |
|  1 |       1 |             1 |
|  2 |       1 |             2 |
|  3 |       2 |             2 |
```

ingredients:

```
| id | ingredient | calories | buy_price | sell_price |
|  1 | Chocolate  |      200 |     12.22 |      14.00 |
|  2 | Sugar      |      300 |     10.50 |      11.50 |
```

But when I run this query all `SUM()` are done for that specifc `ingredients_id`.

The result I would like to get is that everything is still selected like it would without the `WHERE`. But I would still like to get a `SUM()` of all other `ingredients`. So when the `ingredients_id` is 1 or chocolate  I still need to know that calories is a total of `500` and not `200`. So basically a select on `cakes` but now based on the ingredients of the cake.

Now I would expect the ouput to be `1, Chocolate, , , 500, 25.50, ,`; But not with the `Example` cake just the cake where one of the ingredients is chocolate. If the `ingredients_id` is 2 I would expect both cakes to be returned.

I hope the expected result is clear enough to understand if not please let me know.

Comment: If you have already written your query, then show us or atleast your expected output

Comment: Edit your question and show the result you would like to get.  Your query would also be easier to read if you removed all those backticks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am pretty that that what you want is conditional aggregation.  I just can't tell what fields you want it on.  Perhaps:

```
SELECT c.id, c.cake, c.description, c.image,
       SUM(`i`.`calories`) AS `calories`, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN `r`.`ingredients_id` = ? THEN `i`.`sell_price` END) AS ingredient_sell_price, 
       SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(`i`.`time`))) as `time`,
       MIN(CASE WHEN `r`.`ingredients_id` = ? THEN `i`.`stock` END) AS ingredient_stock
FROM cakes c LEFT JOIN 
     recipes r
     ON c.i` = r.cakes_id LEFT JOIN
     ingredients i
     ON r.ingredients_id = i.id
GROUP BY c.id;
```

EDIT:

If you just want cakes that have chocolate, then you would look for the ingredient *after* doing the aggregation:

```
SELECT c.id, c.cake, c.description, c.image,
       SUM(i.calories) AS calories, 
       SUM(i.sell_price) AS ingredient_sell_price, 
       SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(i.time))) as `time`,
       MIN(i.stock) AS ingredient_stock
FROM cakes c LEFT JOIN 
     recipes r
     ON c.i` = r.cakes_id LEFT JOIN
     ingredients i
     ON r.ingredients_id = i.id
GROUP BY c.id
HAVING SUM(r.ingredients_id = ?) > 0;
```

This will return only cakes have have the specific ingredient that you want.

Comment: I have updated the question with a bit more details about the expected results

Comment: Have tested it but it doesn't give me the expected result